# Returning a value from a PDO SQL Server transaction

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm passing a decently sized `SQL` Server `TRANSACTION` via `PDO`, in the following format:

```
$sql = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
       BEGIN TRANSACTION;
       DECLARE @id [int];
           //Check whether specific record exists with a SELECT
           //If it doesn't, create records on two tables
           //Check whether record exists again with another sSELECT (it will now) and assign the selected ID to @id
           //Update records on the two tables where ID = @id
       COMMIT TRANSACTION;";
```

This works fine, and I can happily `UPSERT` all day long. However, I would like to retrieve the value of @id to update the calling object for later use, ideally without needing to write another separate select query, and haven't been able to find a reliable way of getting it.

`fetch()` brings it back when no `INSERTs` are needed (i.e. the record exists, so only the `UPDATEs` are called) but not when the `INSERTs` are called.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617760/php-pdo-mssql-can-not-get-ouput-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, after plenty of experimentation, that the problem was the first `SELECT` statement - when the record existed, it returned a value, and when the record did not exist, it didn't. Adding a second `SELECT` didn't seem to help initially, as it was a seperate result row. Thus, the solution was to advance the resultset by one before getting the contents of the array.

Working query format:

```
$sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON
            SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                DECLARE @id int;
                //Check whether specific record exists with a SELECT
                //If it doesn't, create records on two tables
                //Check whether record exists again with another SELECT (it will now) and assign the selected ID to @id
                //Update records on the two tables where ID = @id
                SELECT @id AS testID
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;";
 $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->nextRowset();
 $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $testID = $result['testID'];
 return $testID;
```